# CodeIgniter SQL correct format for getting data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am quite new to Codeigniter. I have a problem wherein it seems my query is not working. Is it because of my format?

**Model**

```
$this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('
    store_products,
    products,
    category,
    subcategory,
    store,
    store_products_category');
  $this->db->where('store_products_category.store_id', $marketid);
  $this->db->where('store_products_category.subcategory_id', 'subcategory.subcategory_id');
  $this->db->where('subcategory.category_id', 'category.category_id');
  $this->db->where('store_products_category.storeprod_id', 'store_products.storeprod_id');
  $this->db->where('store_products.prod_id', 'products.prod_id');
  $this->db->where('store_products_category.store_id', 'store.store_id');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->row();

  return $result;
```

**Controller**

```
if($marketinfo = $this->MarketModel->getInfobyID($marketid)){
    $data['marketinfolist'] = $marketinfo;
    $this->load->view('layouts/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('clickbasket',$data);
    $this->load->view('navigation/mainfooter');
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
```

It seems that it couldn't return anything from the model. I have already tried doing the query directly on phpmyadmin and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables to get proper result...Like this..

Your Model:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('store_products')
                ->join('products', 'store_products.prod_id = products.prod_id')
                ->join('store_products_category', 'store_products_category.storeprod_id = store_products.storeprod_id')
                ->join('subcategory', 'store_products_category.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id');
                ->join('category', 'subcategory.category_id = category.category_id')
                ->join('store', 'store_products_category.store_id = store.store_id')
                ->where('store_products_category.store_id', $marketid)
                ->get();
$result = $query->row();
return $result;
```

And at your controller..

```
function getMarketInfo($marketid)
   {
     if(!empty($marketid)){
    $marketinfo = $this->MarketModel->getInfobyID($marketid);
    $data['marketinfolist'] = $marketinfo;
    $this->load->view('layouts/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('clickbasket',$data);
    $this->load->view('navigation/mainfooter');
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine now :) just had to adjust the $query->row() part

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding your question correctly then it is happening due to improper join has been applied and code igniter is not able to generate correct query. Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                ->from('store_products')
                ->join('products', 'store_products.prod_id = products.prod_id')
                ->join('store_products_category', 'store_products_category.storeprod_id = store_products.storeprod_id')
                ->join('subcategory', 'store_products_category.subcategory_id = subcategory.subcategory_id');
                ->join('category', 'subcategory.category_id = category.category_id')
                ->join('store', 'store_products_category.store_id = store.store_id')
                ->where('store_products_category.store_id', $marketid)
                ->get();
$result = $query->row();
```

Also, you can print query on browser by following statement and then can copy and execute it in mysql to test it:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

It prints the most recent query executed by current model.